# Convert Reactive to typescript angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some issue on how to convert a Reactive code into typescript. Its a function that will return an HTML code

```
 function ProgressCellRenderer(props) {
        const progress = props.data.completedTasks / props.data.totalTasks;
        return (
          <div>
            <div
              style={{
                position: "absolute",
                width: progress * 100 + "%",
                height: "100%",
                backgroundColor: `rgba(130,210,73,${progress})`
              }}
            />
            <div style={{ position: "absolute" }}>{(progress * 100).toFixed(2)}%</div>
          </div>
        );
      }
```

How can i convert this to an typescript valid function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that directly in Angular.

It's better to move the HTML part to the template file and handle any binding there.

Anyway if you need for any reason to add some HTML from the component class, you can use the `innerHtml` to pass it like the following:

```js
function ProgressCellRenderer(props) {
  const progress = props.data.completedTasks / props.data.totalTasks;
  const htmlString = `
    <div>
      <div
        style="
          position: "absolute";
          width: "${progress * 100}%";
          height: "100%";
          backgroundColor: rgba(130,210,73,${progress})"
      />
      <div style="position: absolute">${(progress * 100).toFixed(2)}%</div>
    </div>
    `;

  return htmlString;
}
```

```html
<div [innerHTML]="htmlString"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent component in Angular looks like this:

```
<div>
  <div style="position: absolute; height: 100%"
       [style.width.%]="progress * 100"
       [style.background-color]="'rgba(130,210,73,' + progress + ')'">
  </div>
  <div style="position:absolute">{{ progress | percent }}</div>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3evqxj?file=src/app/app.component.html